# Link triggers Jquery scroll so element is in center of browser

Tags: jquery, scroll

Is there any way of clicking on a link, which in turn triggers a JQuery function which scrolls the browser down so that a certain element is in the center of the screen?

Comment: If you give the target element an id, just give the link `href="#theid"`

Answer (score 1):

yes there is:

HTML:

```
<a title="News" href="javascript:scrollto('.news');">News</a>
```

JS:

```
function scrollto(element){
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($(element).offset().top)}, 'slow');
};
```

Src: [Pixelbar (german)](http://www.pixelbar.be/blog/mit-jquery-scrollen-gewusst-wie/)

if its not an anker you can use this

```
$(ClickedElement).click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($(element).offset().top)}, 'slow');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method like:

```
$( "#linkID" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$('#linkID').click();
```